# Sidewalk accessibility mapping in California

Tags: data-request, geospatial

I'm looking for a data-driven way to virtually assess accessibility of sidewalks in California, particularly in the Bay Area. Basically, any tools that would help with estimating a 'walkscore' type of rating for sidewalks would be ideal.

FYI - There is a group of researchers at UMD doing something similar for sidewalks in Washington DC. Here's the link: http://sidewalk.umiacs.umd.edu

If you know any tools/ resources/ contacts who would be useful or can point me in the right direction, please let me know.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

[wheelmap](https://wheelmap.org/) is exactly that, built atop osm and open source.

Answer (score 2):

A team at Georgia Tech did an app measuring sidewalk quality based on crowd sourced data.

http://sidewalkscout.ce.gatech.edu/pages/pageMap/pageMobileDevice.php

Answer (score 1):

Here are some resources:

- A thread on the OSM mailing list: https://lists.openstreetmap.org/pipermail/tagging/2017-December/034378.html
- This project aims to standardize sidewalk accessibility data: https://www.opensidewalks.com
- This project aims to standardize place accessibility data in general: https://www.accessibility.cloud – its format includes attributes that are related to sidewalk accessibility.